# Error 404 while executing Microsoft.OData.Client Service?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, odata

I'm getting following error while executing `Microsoft.OData.Client Service`

it simply gives exception `IIS 8.0 Detailed Error - 404.0 - Not Found`

but when I tried the same service Uri using browser it is perfectly running

I tried to call service like following getting exception while executing-

```
MyDataServiceClient myDataServiceClient = new MyDataServiceClient(new Uri("http://localhost:64555/mydev"));
                var query = myDataServiceClient.AllLanguage;
                List<Language> languageList = query.ToList();
```

What is wrong here?
In WebApiConfig.cs

```
private static IEdmModel model = null;
  private static IEdmModel model = null;

        public MyDataServiceClient(Uri serviceRoot)
            : base(serviceRoot, DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3)
        {
            this.Format.LoadServiceModel = this.LoadServiceModel;
            this.Format.UseJson();
        }

        private Microsoft.Data.Edm.IEdmModel LoadServiceModel()
        {
            try
            {

                if (model == null)
                {
                    var metadataUri = this.GetMetadataUri();
                    var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(metadataUri);

                    using (var response = request.GetResponse())
                    using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    using (var reader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(stream))
                    {
                        model = Microsoft.Data.Edm.Csdl.EdmxReader.Parse(reader);
                    }
                }
                return model;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {

                return null;
            }
        }
```

Gives Error :

> Encountered the following errors when parsing the EDMX document: 
>   UnexpectedXmlElement : The element 'edmx:Edmx' was unexpected for the root element. The root element should be Edmx. : (2, 2)

Detail exception

```
System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQueryException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=An error occurred while processing this request.
  Source=Microsoft.Data.Services.Client
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents)
       at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.Execute()
       at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.GetEnumerator()
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
  InnerException: System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceClientException
       HResult=-2146233079
       Message=<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<title>IIS 8.0 Detailed Error - 404.0 - Not Found</title>
```

Comment: There is one a little strange URL detail in Odata Web API -- it is case sensitive. It will return 404 HTTP error if case is incorrect. So check this)

Comment: Actually in WebApiConfig.cs i'm getting this error :`
Encountered the following errors when parsing the EDMX document: 
UnexpectedXmlElement : The element 'edmx:Edmx' was unexpected for the root element. The root element should be Edmx. : (2, 2)`

Comment: @Neo I'm having this same issue when trying to use my existing EF context

Comment: @user3953989 not sure how we tackle this that time, try to update nuget packages , it may resolved

Comment: @Neo I've moved on to trying RESTier now. Please keep this thread updated, I'm interested to see if there is a solution.